# How to POST the contents of a file using curl

Tags: http, post, curl, terminal, mediawiki

I'd like to be able to post the contents of a file to a MediaWiki site.  So far I can do it as so:

```
curl --cookie wikiCookies.txt --negotiate -k -X POST -u:<username> -g 'https://<someWikiSite>/api.php?action=edit&title=TestPage&text=HelloWorld&token=<someToken>&format=json'
```

This works fine, but it has its limitations because of the length of the url.

Suppose I had a file foo.txt, how could I post the contents of this file to a MediaWiki site so that I wouldn't have to add the entire file contents to the url?

I've found the MediaWiki API http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit#Editing_pages, but I haven't been able to figure out how to curl POST entire file contents with it.

I think this should be a fairly simple question for anyone with a good understanding of curl, but no matter what I try, I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
--data "text=<some_wiki_tag>this is encoded wiki content</some_wiki_tag>&title=TestPage&text=HelloWorld&token=<someToken>&format=json"
```

Comment: I tried this: `curl --cookie newcookies.txt --negotiate -k --data @hi.txt -X POST -u:<username> 'https://wiki.com/api.php?action=edit&title=<Page Title>&text=@hi.txt&token=<token>&format=json'` but all this did was add the text "@hi.txt" to the wiki

Comment: Try to post on url `'https://wiki.com/api.php'` without any params (or "?" at the end).

Comment: Nope, still just adds the text "@hi.txt"

Comment: Yep, I saw that in [example](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit#Editing_via_Ajax) file doesn't post. You should post file content, not file. Try to use --data with `text=<wiki>wiki text</wiki>` without any file. POST params shouldn't have lenght limitations.

Comment: Can you write out what the entire command would be.  I'm not sure if I follow

Comment: `curl --cookie newcookies.txt --negotiate -k -X POST --data 'title=Page Title&text=<some_wiki_tag>this is encoded wiki content</some_wiki_tag>&token=<token>&format=json' -u:<username> -g 'https://<someWikiSite>/api.php?action=edit'`

Comment: I'll give you the bounty in 7 hours

Comment: Thanks, some clarification: curl has ability to post file on server using "@" with file name, sometimes it's necessary. In current API you shouldn't post file, but you should post file content. That's why you should manually read file content, encode it and use as field value.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the `-d, --data <data>`

If the `<data>` starts with `@` then the rest should be a file name whose content will be send in the POST request.

Online curl [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

> -d, --data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the
>   data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.
>
> -d, --data is the same as --data-ascii. To post data purely binary, you should instead use the --data-binary option. To URL-encode the
>   value of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.
>
> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command
>   line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a
>   separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would
>   generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.
>
> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file
>   name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data
>   from stdin. The contents of the file must already be URL-encoded.
>   Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named
>   'foobar' would thus be done with --data @foobar. When --data is told
>   to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be
>   stripped out.

Comment: I've tried the above with this command: `curl --cookie newcookies.txt --negotiate -k --data @hi.txt -X POST -u:<username> '<wikiURL>?action=edit&title=<Page Title>&token=<token>&format=json'`  however, I get this response: `{"error":{"code":"notext","info":"One of the text, appendtext, prependtext and undo parameters must be set"}}`